# Bounded differentiation operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Is there an example of a normed space $X$, $\dim X=\infty$ such that the differentiation operator $T=\frac{d}{dx}$ is bounded, meaning that $T \in B(X)$ ?

Comment: $X=\{0\}$ comes to mind.

Comment: Slightly less trivial: any finite dimensional space of differentiable functions as the space of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Oh, of course, if $\dim X < \infty$, then every operator is bounded. But I was looking for an example in the infinite dimensional case. (So, I have now added the dimension $=\infty$ condition in the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of all functions of the form
$$
     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}f(s)e^{-isx}ds, \;\; f \in L^2[-R,R].
$$
This is a linear space over $\mathbb{C}$. You can use the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ norm on $X$. By the Plancherel Theorem,
$$
          \left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}f(s)e^{-isx}ds\right\|=\|f\|_{L^2[-R,R]}.
$$
This space $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space because it is unitarily equivalent to $L^2[-R,R]$.

The functions in $X$ are infinitely differentiable, with
\begin{align}
       \left\|\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}f(s)e^{-isx}ds\right\| 
      & = \left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}(-is)f(s)e^{-isx}ds\right\| \\
      & = \left(\int_{-R}^{R}s^2|f(s)|^2ds\right)^{1/2}\\
      & \le R\left(\int_{-R}^{R}|f(s)|^2ds\right)^{1/2}\\
   & =R\left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}f(s)e^{-isx}ds\right\|
\end{align}
So the differentiation operator is bounded on $X$ with a bound of $R$.

Comment: $X$ is complete, right?

Comment: @CameronWilliams : Yes, it is unitarily equivalent to $L^2[-R,R]$ by Plancherel's Theorem. This is a spectral projection onto a bounded part of the spectrum of the differentiation operator. :)

Comment: I somehow had completely missed that remark in your post. My bad!

Comment: @TrialAndError: Thanks! Indeed, the Fourier transform changes the roles of the differentiation and multiplication operators.

Comment: @Eeyore : If you like the answer, you can select the checkmark and/or accept it has an answer. By the way, this type of technique works or every unbounded selfadjoint operator. The idea comes from the Spectral Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Another example: Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an interval and $X=\{f\in C^\infty(I)\mid \sup_{n\geq 0}\|f^{(n)}\|_\infty<\infty\}$ endowed with the norm $\|f\|_X=\sup_{n\geq 0}\|f^{(n)}\|_\infty$. Then $\|f'\|_X=\sup_{n\geq 1}\|f^{(n)}\|_\infty\leq \|f\|_X$. If $I$ is bounded, then $X$ contains all polynomials, so it's certainly infinite-dimensional.

Of course, this can be done more generally: Let $Y$ be a normed space and $T\colon D(T)\to Y$ a linear operator defined on a subspace $D(T)\subset Y$. Let $X=\{u\in\bigcap_{n\geq 0} D(T^n)\mid \sup_{n\geq 0}\|T^n u\|_Y<\infty\}$ with norm $\|u\|_X=\sup_{n\geq 0}\|T^n u\|_Y$. Then $T\colon X\to X$ is bounded. If $X$ is infinite-dimensional depends on the operator $T$.

Remark: As usual, $D(T^n)$ is defined recursively by $D(T^{n+1})=\{u\in D(T)\mid Tu\in D(T^n)\}$.

Comment: Thanks! But did you mean that $f \in C^\infty(I)$  ?

Comment: @Eeyore: You're right. I corrected it.

Comment: But can we take $X$ as the set of smooth functions on $R$ rather than on an interval?

Comment: Yes. In this case, all functions of the form $\sin(\alpha\,\cdot)$ with $|\alpha|\leq 1$ are contained in $X$, and they form an infinite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: I don't understand something here. Isn't the space of test functions ${\mathcal D}({\mathbb R})$ a subspace of $C^\infty({\mathbb R})$?  Then does it mean that $||f||_X$ makes ${\mathcal D}({\mathbb R})$ a normed space?

Comment: If $f\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, then every derivative of $f$ is bounded, but they are not necessarily uniformly bounded. So $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is not contained in $X$.

Comment: @MaoWao In what reference could I find that space with said norm?

Comment: @eraldcoil I don't know.